# Random undefined reference to main - there is a main & goes away on its own without changes

Tags: gcc, cmake

Every once and a while, make errors out with

```
/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But there IS A MAIN.  This happens on programs that are on build version 50+, and have had a main for months or years.

Best part is if I run make again, doing absolutely NOTHING inbetween, it compiles just fine.

It's a complex build, order of magnitude 50,000 lines of code, cannot realistically reduce to a simple test case.  Not worth spending time trying to diagnose, since just re-running make gets past it.  But, hoping someone else has encountered this random frustration before.

Perhaps I've made an error somewhere in my CMakeLists.txt files, which allow this to happen periodically but then go away for about 20 more builds.  Perhaps there's a rare bug in CMake version 2.6-patch 4, gcc 4.7.0, or ld 2.17.50.0.6-20.el5_8.3, but I'm not finding any other mention of this among the haystack of programmers who actually left out main.  At some point I'll be updating cmake and gcc...

Comment: do you only see this with multithreaded builds? or single threaded as well?

Comment: All of the code I have been actively working on is single threaded.  All the multi-threaded programs haven't been changed for quite some time, and are not being compiled because they're not libraries -- but end programs that aren't having make ran on their projects.

Comment: I meant, do you see this problem if you build with "make -j1"?

Comment: Yes.  Managed to be unaware that make could operate multithreaded.  Although I'll try using it in the future, I've never supplied the -j option, so it defaults to -j1 and executes everything serially.

Comment: I assume your add_executable line looks something like  "add_executable(exe_name ... file_with_main.c ...)".
If so, check the generated makefiles to make sure exe_name is explicitly depending on file_with_main.c (via a /path/to/exe_name: /path/to/file_with_main.c rule)

Comment: Yes, "add_executable(app_name file_with_main.cpp additional_file.cpp)"

Comment: And, Makefile is visible at: http://pastebin.com/mAdfFTKu

Comment: Have managed to never have to work directly with Makefile's, so I'm not familiar enough with the syntax to check if it's explicitly depending.

Comment: Oh, I think here it is.  in BUILD-APP-DIR/CMakeFiles/app_name.dir/depend.make, the last line is: "APP-DIR/CMakeFiles/app_name.dir/app_name.cpp.o: ../APP-DIR/app_name.cpp" so I think that's what you were saying to check for.

Comment: I'm assuming app_name.cpp has main(): in either build.make or depend.make (don't remember which) there should be a line like "APP-DIR/CMakeFiles/app_name.dir/app_name: APP-DIR/CMakeFiles/app_name.dir/app_name.cpp.o"

Comment: if the above is true, you could try running "make clean; make -d app_name > output.txt", and manually parsing through what make is doing.  It might be time consuming, but it will tell you exactly what is going on.